# How to give escape sequences for user defined Inputs

Tags: java

I had an application in which my user input is to give the desired length of String elements separated by 
***`:`***(colon)

My code to parse it is like this

```
String str[] = input.split(":");
```

But I am getting erroneous results when the user strings have ***:*** in between them.

I tried to use the string using **`\:`**, but it never worked.

The sample user string may be like this **1:2:3**

The expected value here is

```
str[0] = "1";
str[1] = "2";
str[2] = "3";
```

and is the same as actual

But if the String is like this **`1:Title 1`  : `2: Title 2` :   `3: Title 3`**

The expected value here is

```
str[0] = "1: Title 1";
str[1] = "2: Title 2";
str[2] = "3: Title 3";
```

and is the not same as actual,

```
str[0] = "1";
str[1] = "Title 1";
str[2] = "2";
str[3] = "Title 2";
str[4] = "3";
str[5] = "Title 3";
```

How can I overcome this ?

Comment: And the string you are going to split is ?

Comment: Please post the result you get and the desired result.

Comment: What do you expect in this case `1:Title 1  : 2: Title 2 :   3: Title 3`?

Comment: you dont have to escape `:`..while using it in spilt.. it works.. i think you are expecting something else out of your input string

Comment: You should use regex and simple : split will not give you what you intend

Comment: Why are you using colon as the delimiter if colon is in itself a valid  input character? Assuming you don't expect `$#` in the input, you could use `$#` as the value separator.

Comment: @zEro, the user may provide any symbol as the input.. but we have fixed ourselves to colon as delimiter, since we have used the same in previous projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use spaces around the splitting colon: `split(" : ")`. This assumes that an ordinary colon in text will ordinarily not have a space in front.

Not much of an answer, but otherwise you'll need to specify some representation of a non-splitting colon, and handle it. For instance `replace("\\:", "§")` and after splitting `replace("§", ":")`.

Comment: @HarshavardhanKonakanchi If you use this solution, you must also make sure to validate that the user input does not contain colons surrounded by spaces, when the user input is entered. Because if you just split on colon surrounded by spaces, it will fail again the next day when you get the user input like `1 : Title 1`.

Comment: @Alderath Yes.. But I never said that I am goig to use : with spaces. I had my own algorithms

Answer (score 0):

The method `String.split()` doesn't deal with the escaping automatically, and you should define it explicitly by yourself using regular expression. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962925/escape-comma-when-using-string-split) may help you.

Here is the snippet,

```
String input = "1\\:Title 1:2\\:Title 2:3\\:Title 3";
String[] strs = input.split("(?<!\\\\):");
for (String str : strs) {
    System.out.println(str.replace("\\:", ":"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should work for you:

```
String str = "1:Title 1  : 2: Title 2 :   3: Title 3";
String[] arr = str.split("\\s*:(?=\\s*\\d)\\s*");
System.out.printf("Split: %s%n", Arrays.toString(arr));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Split: [1:Title 1, 2: Title 2, 3: Title 3]
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/8yeGns

Comment: I can't use regexp , since I don't expect the format of input from user... As per you, it is fine for fixed format as in my example

Comment: Just fyi whatever sting you're providing in split function is indeed a regex.