# How to split string to arguments like shell?

Tags: java, regex, string, args4j

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/is-there-a-good-command-line-argument-parser-for-java) is a list of argument parser, but they accept string array.

Now, I got a string like

```
-s -d "String with space" -d "string with \" escape \n the next line"
```

I want to split the string to

```
-s
-d
String with space
-d
string with " escape
the next line (This is one string with \n)
```

Is there any tool to do this ?

**SEE ALSO**

- [split-string-on-spaces-except-if-between-quotes-i-e-treat-hello-world-as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804335/)
- [split-a-string-containing-command-line-parameters-into-a-string-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259143/)

**EDTIED**

Post as answer.

Comment: Gee `String` `split` hmm try `String.split`

Comment: Duplicate of this perhaps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804335/split-string-on-spaces-except-if-between-quotes-i-e-treat-hello-world-as

Comment: @aioobe in that topic there are no escape sequences.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg, Should be trivial to fix with a negative look-behind. See for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962925/escape-comma-when-using-string-split

Comment: @aioobe I fond it after I post~

Comment: @aioobe This problem can not be solved with a trivial negative look behind.  That doesn't cover hard-quotes vs soft-quotes, nested quotes, an escaped-escape character etc.  
  I believe it can be done completely using perl-style extended regex, but it gets pretty ugly.

Comment: You can find good answers [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/is-there-a-good-command-line-argument-parser-for-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fond [ArgumentTokenizer](http://sourceforge.net/p/drjava/git_repo/ci/master/tree/drjava/src/edu/rice/cs/util/ArgumentTokenizer.java) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28640859/1870054),it's just a single class and solve the question.

```
/*BEGIN_COPYRIGHT_BLOCK
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2001-2010, JavaPLT group at Rice University (drjava@rice.edu)
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 *    * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *      notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *    * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *      notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *      documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *    * Neither the names of DrJava, the JavaPLT group, Rice University, nor the
 *      names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products
 *      derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
 * A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
 * PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 * This software is Open Source Initiative approved Open Source Software.
 * Open Source Initative Approved is a trademark of the Open Source Initiative.
 *
 * This file is part of DrJava.  Download the current version of this project
 * from http://www.drjava.org/ or http://sourceforge.net/projects/drjava/
 *
 * END_COPYRIGHT_BLOCK*/

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
/**
 * Utility class which can tokenize a String into a list of String arguments,
 * with behavior similar to parsing command line arguments to a program.
 * Quoted Strings are treated as single arguments, and escaped characters
 * are translated so that the tokenized arguments have the same meaning.
 * Since all methods are static, the class is declared abstract to prevent
 * instantiation.
 *
 * @version $Id$
 */
public abstract class ArgumentTokenizer
{
    private static final int NO_TOKEN_STATE = 0;
    private static final int NORMAL_TOKEN_STATE = 1;
    private static final int SINGLE_QUOTE_STATE = 2;
    private static final int DOUBLE_QUOTE_STATE = 3;

    /**
     * Tokenizes the given String into String tokens
     *
     * @param arguments A String containing one or more command-line style arguments to be tokenized.
     * @return A list of parsed and properly escaped arguments.
     */
    public static List<String> tokenize(String arguments)
    {
        return tokenize(arguments, false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (String s : tokenize("-s -d \"String with space\" -d \"string with \\\" escape \\n the next line\""))
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Tokenizes the given String into String tokens.
     *
     * @param arguments A String containing one or more command-line style arguments to be tokenized.
     * @param stringify whether or not to include escape special characters
     * @return A list of parsed and properly escaped arguments.
     */
    public static List<String> tokenize(String arguments, boolean stringify)
    {

        LinkedList<String> argList = new LinkedList<String>();
        StringBuilder currArg = new StringBuilder();
        boolean escaped = false;
        int state = NO_TOKEN_STATE;  // start in the NO_TOKEN_STATE
        int len = arguments.length();

        // Loop over each character in the string
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            char c = arguments.charAt(i);
            if (escaped)
            {
                // Escaped state: just append the next character to the current arg.
                escaped = false;
                currArg.append(c);
            } else
            {
                switch (state)
                {
                    case SINGLE_QUOTE_STATE:
                        if (c == '\'')
                        {
                            // Seen the close quote; continue this arg until whitespace is seen
                            state = NORMAL_TOKEN_STATE;
                        } else
                        {
                            currArg.append(c);
                        }
                        break;
                    case DOUBLE_QUOTE_STATE:
                        if (c == '"')
                        {
                            // Seen the close quote; continue this arg until whitespace is seen
                            state = NORMAL_TOKEN_STATE;
                        } else if (c == '\\')
                        {
                            // Look ahead, and only escape quotes or backslashes
                            i++;
                            char next = arguments.charAt(i);
                            if (next == '"' || next == '\\')
                            {
                                currArg.append(next);
                            } else
                            {
                                currArg.append(c);
                                currArg.append(next);
                            }
                        } else
                        {
                            currArg.append(c);
                        }
                        break;
//          case NORMAL_TOKEN_STATE:
//            if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
//              // Whitespace ends the token; start a new one
//              argList.add(currArg.toString());
//              currArg = new StringBuffer();
//              state = NO_TOKEN_STATE;
//            }
//            else if (c == '\\') {
//              // Backslash in a normal token: escape the next character
//              escaped = true;
//            }
//            else if (c == '\'') {
//              state = SINGLE_QUOTE_STATE;
//            }
//            else if (c == '"') {
//              state = DOUBLE_QUOTE_STATE;
//            }
//            else {
//              currArg.append(c);
//            }
//            break;
                    case NO_TOKEN_STATE:
                    case NORMAL_TOKEN_STATE:
                        switch (c)
                        {
                            case '\\':
                                escaped = true;
                                state = NORMAL_TOKEN_STATE;
                                break;
                            case '\'':
                                state = SINGLE_QUOTE_STATE;
                                break;
                            case '"':
                                state = DOUBLE_QUOTE_STATE;
                                break;
                            default:
                                if (!Character.isWhitespace(c))
                                {
                                    currArg.append(c);
                                    state = NORMAL_TOKEN_STATE;
                                } else if (state == NORMAL_TOKEN_STATE)
                                {
                                    // Whitespace ends the token; start a new one
                                    argList.add(currArg.toString());
                                    currArg = new StringBuilder();
                                    state = NO_TOKEN_STATE;
                                }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new IllegalStateException("ArgumentTokenizer state " + state + " is invalid!");
                }
            }
        }

        // If we're still escaped, put in the backslash
        if (escaped)
        {
            currArg.append('\\');
            argList.add(currArg.toString());
        }
        // Close the last argument if we haven't yet
        else if (state != NO_TOKEN_STATE)
        {
            argList.add(currArg.toString());
        }
        // Format each argument if we've been told to stringify them
        if (stringify)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < argList.size(); i++)
            {
                argList.set(i, "\"" + _escapeQuotesAndBackslashes(argList.get(i)) + "\"");
            }
        }
        return argList;
    }

    /**
     * Inserts backslashes before any occurrences of a backslash or
     * quote in the given string.  Also converts any special characters
     * appropriately.
     */
    protected static String _escapeQuotesAndBackslashes(String s)
    {
        final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(s);

        // Walk backwards, looking for quotes or backslashes.
        //  If we see any, insert an extra backslash into the buffer at
        //  the same index.  (By walking backwards, the index into the buffer
        //  will remain correct as we change the buffer.)
        for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if ((c == '\\') || (c == '"'))
            {
                buf.insert(i, '\\');
            }
            // Replace any special characters with escaped versions
            else if (c == '\n')
            {
                buf.deleteCharAt(i);
                buf.insert(i, "\\n");
            } else if (c == '\t')
            {
                buf.deleteCharAt(i);
                buf.insert(i, "\\t");
            } else if (c == '\r')
            {
                buf.deleteCharAt(i);
                buf.insert(i, "\\r");
            } else if (c == '\b')
            {
                buf.deleteCharAt(i);
                buf.insert(i, "\\b");
            } else if (c == '\f')
            {
                buf.deleteCharAt(i);
                buf.insert(i, "\\f");
            }
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works if you have something like this `String command = "--mode 0 --password \"my \\pass\"word\"";`? The quote in the middle of password is not preserved, whereas bash seems to keep it.

Comment: I don't check the code yet, but you example seems missing two \, should be \\\"

Comment: Ah, seems I confused myself there. Thanks