# How to split a string into command line arguments like the shell in python?

Tags: python, argparse

I have command line arguments in a string and I need to split it to feed to `argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args`.

I see that [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) uses `string.split()` plentifully. However in complex cases, this does not work, such as

```
--foo "spaces in brakets"  --bar escaped\ spaces
```

Is there a functionality to do that in python?

(*A similar question for java was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162368/how-to-split-string-to-arguments-like-shell)*).

Comment: what should be the ouput exactly of `argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args`

Comment: You need to show us a full program that demonstrates the specific problem you are having, with example input that triggers it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're parsing a windows-style command line, then `shlex.split` doesn't work correctly - calling `subprocess` functions on the result will not have the same behavior as passing the string directly to the shell.

In that case, the most reliable way to split a string like the command-line arguments to python is... to pass command line arguments to python:

```py
import sys
import subprocess
import shlex
import json  # json is an easy way to send arbitrary ascii-safe lists of strings out of python

def shell_split(cmd):
    """
    Like `shlex.split`, but uses the Windows splitting syntax when run on Windows.

    On windows, this is the inverse of subprocess.list2cmdline
    """
    if os.name == 'posix':
        return shlex.split(cmd)
    else:
        # TODO: write a version of this that doesn't invoke a subprocess
        if not cmd:
            return []
        full_cmd = '{} {}'.format(
            subprocess.list2cmdline([
                sys.executable, '-c',
                'import sys, json; print(json.dumps(sys.argv[1:]))'
            ]), cmd
        )
        ret = subprocess.check_output(full_cmd).decode()
        return json.loads(ret)
```

One example of how these differ:

```py
# windows does not treat all backslashes as escapes
>>> shell_split(r'C:\Users\me\some_file.txt "file with spaces"', 'file with spaces')
['C:\\Users\\me\\some_file.txt', 'file with spaces']

# posix does
>>> shlex.split(r'C:\Users\me\some_file.txt "file with spaces"')
['C:Usersmesome_file.txt', 'file with spaces']

# non-posix does not mean Windows - this produces extra quotes
>>> shlex.split(r'C:\Users\me\some_file.txt "file with spaces"', posix=False)
['C:\\Users\\me\\some_file.txt', '"file with spaces"']
```

Answer (score 32):

This is what [`shlex.split` was created for](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split).

Comment: Nice! And it's available since Python 2.3.

Comment: Does `shlex.split` have an issue with escaped quote marks? e.g `--foo "bar\"baz"`

Comment: @user1735003: Yes, though it would usually be the shell handling this for you (`shlex` follows mostly the same rules as `sh` shell rules). But if you have a constructed command line like that, it's fine with it, that's the whole point of `shlex`: `shlex.split(r'--foo "bar\"baz"')` produces `['--foo', 'bar"baz']`. The `argparse` docs are [being lazy](https://bugs.python.org/issue20598) when they use `str.split` instead of `shlex.split` (or explicit lists); they were going for brevity, but without the mental load of requiring `shlex` knowledge.

Comment: This works great for POSIX systems, but doesn't help if you want to split arguments from a windows format.

Comment: @Eric: Given there is no single Windows format (Windows executables receive the raw string and parse it themselves), and that the question was about parsing a string for `argparse` to work with (which has a fixed behavior regardless of OS), your comment doesn't seem particularly relevant to this case.

Comment: Even though windows receives the raw string, most programs define a `main(argc, argv)`, which end up using the parsing provided by their C runtime. `argparse` has a fixed behavior regardless of OS, but that's because it takes a list of strings as an input, typically `sys.argv`. How `sys.argv` gets populated _is_ platform-dependent, and it's worth drawing attention to that. `shlex.split` matches the way `sys.argv` is populated on posix systems, but not how it is populated on windows systems.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`split_arg_string`](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/master/click/parser.py#L97) helper function from the [`click`](http://click.pocoo.org/) package:

```
import re

def split_arg_string(string):
    """Given an argument string this attempts to split it into small parts."""
    rv = []
    for match in re.finditer(r"('([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'"
                             r'|"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"'
                             r'|\S+)\s*', string, re.S):
        arg = match.group().strip()
        if arg[:1] == arg[-1:] and arg[:1] in '"\'':
            arg = arg[1:-1].encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace') \
                .decode('unicode-escape')
        try:
            arg = type(string)(arg)
        except UnicodeError:
            pass
        rv.append(arg)
    return rv
```

For example:

```
>>> print split_arg_string('"this is a test" 1 2 "1 \\" 2"')
['this is a test', '1', '2', '1 " 2']
```

The `click` package is starting to dominate for command-arguments parsing, but I don't think it supports parsing arguments from string (only from `argv`). The helper function above is used only for `bash` completion.

**Edit**: I can nothing but recommend to use the [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) as suggested in the answer by @ShadowRanger. The only reason I'm not deleting this answer is because it provides *a little bit faster splitting* then the full-blown pure-python tokenizer used in `shlex` (around 3.5x faster for the example above, 5.9us vs 20.5us). However, this shouldn't be a reason to prefer it over `shlex`.